# How to treat response objects in python?

Tags: json, list, python-2.7, get, response

Ok i got a response using the reply command

```
reply = requests.get(http://api.eve-central.com/api/route/from/Jita/to/New Caldari
```

I have trouble dealing with the recieved data, isolating the data i want.
How can get for example the value of the `to: region: regionid:` path?

This is what i get by using `print reply.json()` (`reply.json()`'s type is list):

```
[{u'to':
{u'region':
{u'regionid': 10000002, u'name': u'The Forge'},
u'security': 1.0, u'systemid': 30000145, u'name': u'New Caldari', u'constellationid': 20000020},
u'from':
{u'region':
{u'regionid': 10000002, u'name': u'The Forge'},
u'security': 0.9, u'systemid': 30000142, u'name': u'Jita', u'constellationid': 20000020}, u'secChange': False}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON data is a list(`[]`) that contains dictionaries. To access list elements, you use `my_list[index]`, where `index` starts at `0`. To access dictionary elements, you use `my_dict[key]`, where `key` is the key of the dictionary's element you want to get.

To access the "to: region: regionid"-path, you'd do the following:

```
to_region_id = reply.json()[0]['to']['region']['regionid']
```

Comment: This gives code produces and error, but through some testing i found that what you probably meant was `reply.json()[0]['to']['region']['regionid']`

As I mentioned reply is a Response object and as such cannot accept indicators according to python, i think cause it gives me the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gregoriam\dot\Api.py", line 15, in <module>
    to_region_id = reply[0]['to']['region']['regionid']
TypeError: 'Response' object does not support indexing`

Comment: But provided that you use `to_region_id = reply.json()[0]['to']['region']['regionid']` you get the desired result.
Long story short the way i understood your asnwer was the following: reply.json() is a list containing one object which has something called "dictionaries" (I am gonna google that) which probably like a type of storing data in a nice a uniform manner.
P.S. Please edit your anwer and replace reply with reply.json() so I can accept it. Thanks :)